# SUPEE 7405 Hunk #1 failed at 171

Tags: supee-7405

ERROR Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully - This is on Magento ver. 1.9.2.0

Any ideas on how to proceed?

Comment: I had the same problem. After installing the previous patches (In my case 6788 and 7616) I was able to install the 7405 patch without any problems. In the file /app/etc/applied.patches.list you will find which patches are already installed.

Answer (score 1):

In SUPEE-6788 the file

```
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php
```

was overwritten and SUPEE-7405 wants to overwrite it again. If it does not match the expected appearance, there is a problem.

A "hack" is sadly not easy, because in around line 170 the new patch adds something at the same part as patch 6788 was editing, so it's not only the line number which is not equal. In my case I have problems with 6788 (with a module), so I have to find another solution, but probably in your case the easiest way would be to install 6788 before 7405 :)

Answer (score 1):

Problem was a lack of .htaccess.sample. Copied one from a clean install