# Troubles with applying patches to Magento 1.9.2.0

Tags: magento-1.9, patches, supee-7405

I'm having troubles patching Magento 1.9.2.0.
Applying patch supee-7045 failed and I searched for a solution, and I have put the .htaccess and .htaccess.sample from a clean install into my Magento folder. I've also tried to install other previous patches. Just like suggested in this article (I had the same error): [SUPEE 7405 Hunk #1 failed at 171](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/98370/supee-7405-hunk-1-failed-at-171)

Patches supee-5344 en supee-5994 according to applied.patches.lists are installed. So I started with installing supee-6482, since from this patch there is a 1.9.2.0 patch is available. However trying to install this results in this error:

> sh PATCH_SUPEE-6482_CE_1.9.2.0_v1-2015-08-03-06-51-10.sh
>
> PATCH_SUPEE-6482_CE_1.9.2.0_v1-2015-08-03-06-51-10.sh: 14:
> PATCH_SUPEE-6482_CE_1.9.2.0_v1-2015-08-03-06-51-10.sh: 127: not found
> PATCH_SUPEE-6482_CE_1.9.2.0_v1-2015-08-03-06-51-10.sh: 14:
> PATCH_SUPEE-6482_CE_1.9.2.0_v1-2015-08-03-06-51-10.sh: 127: not found
> PATCH_SUPEE-6482_CE_1.9.2.0_v1-2015-08-03-06-51-10.sh: 25:
> PATCH_SUPEE-6482_CE_1.9.2.0_v1-2015-08-03-06-51-10.sh: 0: not found
> Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
> -e ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.
>
> checking file app/code/core/Mage/Api/Model/Server/Adapter/Soap.php
> Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
> Apply anyway? [n]  Skipping patch. 1 out of 1 hunk ignored checking
> file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Api/V2.php

Comment: Now I've tried to install the patches by overwriting the files with the files that already are patched. I found them here: https://github.com/magecomp/Magento-Pre-Patched-Files , everything looks okay, but I've discovered that my checkout process doesn't work properly. When a users confirms an order, an order is placed in the back-end, but the user isn't redirected to the payment provider and the page looks like nothing happend... No good

Answer (score 1):

First of all, are you using a code versioning system (CVS) like Git? It would be a more reliable "source of truth" on which patches were applied or not. So I'd strongly recommend it if you're not using it.

The patch probably can't be applied because you have a modified core file (Soap.php). Some .htaccess file(s) might also be causing issues like you mentioned.

Here's what I would do to make sure all patches are applied properly:

1. Since you're already on Magento 1.9.2, I'd just download the source code for 1.9.2.3 and apply it directly on top of your existing code. If you didn't manually add features to the core files then that should be enough. Here's where a CVS would be useful, so you can see exactly what changed when doing that. If you don't have a CVS you should at least manually diff all core code and design files with a backup to make sure the only changes are those related to the patches and that you're not losing any features.
2. Another thing you could do is revert the Soap.php and any affected .htaccess files to their original state first (as in 1.9.2.0) and then apply the patch again.

Comment: For approach #1, it would of course be even better if you have your extensions and customizations on their own repository (using modman or similar) - then you can delete all 1.9.2.0 core files FIRST and then add the 1.9.2.3 core files back. The benefit would be that then you won't have any "orphan" files left after doing that. There are other ways of doing that but I'm only describing what I'd consider the easier ways.

Comment: Oh, and regarding your last comment about the checkout: if you revert back to the state before using the "Magento-Pre-Patched_files" repo then everything works? Either way, I wouldn't use that repo: use 1.9.2.3 instead.

Comment: yes, I've made a backup before doing so, and just put the backup back and it works again

Comment: I don't have that much experience in Magento. At the moment I'm trying to update an existing shop, that someone else made, no CVS, so I have very little info on the changes. So I'm not very confident replacing or deleting files like that. I've got my backup, but this is so massive it takes hours to copy on the server itself. Downloading it to my local machine is nearly impossible. It would take days to do so...

Comment: Soap.php seems the same as 1.9.2.0

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this pdf

http://info2.magento.com/rs/magentosoftware/images/Installing-a-Patch-for-Magento-Community-Edition.pdf

May be it will help you.

It shows

How to install patches using putty.

How to give file permission before install.

And it works for me.